# How to do escape sequence for *@ in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

In my MVC program
I need to create a jquery function to check email validation
and regular expression which i am trying to use is below

```
var v =/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i;
```

but the symbols `*@` in between will consider as comment and giving errors. How to escape this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `@` with `\x40` to make sure the regex engine gets a `@` literal.

BTW, you can always check a symbol code using this [*Unicode code converter*](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) (or any other converter, but I like that one).